# rsync with just a single rule file, exclude some paths but include selected sub-paths therein, recursively

Tags: rsync

I want to exclude all the contents of a folder but some of its sub-folders, and I want to do it with just a single rule file without adding `--exclude` or `--include` command-line options. Is this possible? A single rule file is important because I find it easier to maintain and document.

I run the following command

```
rsync -a -F --filter "merge backup-filter" /mnt/home/common /mnt/backup
```

with file `backup-filter`:

```
# non-rooted rules take precedence
+ .git/*
+ .gitignore
- .*.sw?

# rooted rules
+ /common/backup*
- /common/opt/
+ /common/usr/

# FIXME
+ /common/root/startup/*
+ /common/root/.config/gopt/*
- /common/root/*
```

And two `.rsync-filter` files

```
# cat ./usr/bin/.rsync-filter
# Assume command-line option --filter=':- .gitignore', which
# backs up all file/folders that aren't listed in ./.gitignore

# cat ./usr/.rsync-filter
+ usr/bin
- */
```

The rule block starting at `FIXME` is the broken piece. It is meant to exclude all the contents of `/common/root` but let the contents of `startup` and `.config/gopt` be copied. It is broken because `startup` and `.config/gopt` aren't copied.

As time goes by, I plan on adding more excluded paths at various levels and some included sub-paths like I'm doing here for the `/common/root` path. So the rule file is going to grow considerably.

Comment: You use `-F`, but you don't show what's inside your `.rsync-filter` files.

Comment: @ams thanks for catching my oversight. `.rsync-filter` files added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
+ /common/root/startup/
+ /common/root/startup/*
+ /common/root/.config/
+ /common/root/.config/gopt/
+ /common/root/.config/gopt/*
- /common/root/.config/*
- /common/root/*
```

Or, maybe this, if you didn't really want to override later file-specific rules:

```
+ /common/root/startup/
+ /common/root/.config/
+ /common/root/.config/gopt/
- /common/root/.config/*
- /common/root/*
```

The problem was that it never recursed into `startup` or `.config` because the `- /common/root/*` told it not to.

This version says explictly that you *do* want those directories. You have to do this for all parent directory levels if you want to cherry pick subdirectories, like this.

Another trick is to include *all directories* with `+ */`, near the top, and then exclude *files* you don't want with `- /common/root/**`. You can then tidy up the clutter of empty directories with `--prune-empty-dirs`, but beware that this will prume *real* empty directories, as well as ones whose content you chose to exclude.

Comment: yes, the first block answers my question - I plan to ponder the second one too, but I'm satisfied. I'll accept your answer in a couple of day, just in case someone else chimes in. Forget and correct me if that's not the right SA etiquette, I'm new around here.

Comment: If you accept now, you can change your mind later, I think.

Comment: I accepted your answer, thank you. I couldn't also upvote it because my reputation is still under the minimum.